# Multiple ssl certificates with one ip and same port but different host headers is having problems in one domain (IIS 10)

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, iis-10, bindings

I have post this question in stackoverflow, but seems not quite get the solutions. So I think serverfault will be more appropriate place to ask the question.

I have iis 10.0 which host two domains ssl cert, say 1 is [www.rtx.com](http://www.rtx.com) and the another is [www.dfg.com](http://www.dfg.com), both domain are pointing to the same ip with iis10. So I can access the same webpage with either https://www.rtx.com/calculation.aspx or
https://www.dfg.com/calculation.aspx both. The problem is that for most page, both domain work properply, but for some webpage in one domain e.g dfg.com https://www.dfg.com/calculation.aspx, it cannot be loaded, in firefox, it returns

```
The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.
```

And in Chrome, it returns.

```
The webpage at https://.../ReminderSettings.aspx?indicatortype=survey might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address. ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

So what is the reason that some page cannot be accessed in one domain but can in another domain? How can I solve this problem? Is it caused by the cert problem?

Comment: Before making a good IIS question, you must learn the actual terms you should use. There is no "two domains" on IIS, but sites, applications, and virtual directories, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis Without a proper description readers won't easily know how you configured IIS.

Comment: The connection is turned to insucre connection for the asset in chrome